# Android Studio , tooltip disappearing so fast

Tags: android, android-studio

I have the following issue , i want to copy the error text from this tooltip but once i mouse-over it, it disappears so fast... and its driving me crazy :) :

[image]

I have the following android studio version :

[image]

I have the following Settings :

[image]

Thanks for the help,

Comment: For me, it was a plugin that was causing this issue. Check if you have installed any plugin recently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on your screenshot a bit, "Value tooltip delay (ms):" only allows one to adjust the delay before a tooltip *appears*, but not before it disappears.

It seems that Windows allows application developers to [control the tooltip removal timeout](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/tooltips-with-infinite-timeout),*(1)* but that Android Studio (like most applications) has not included an adjustment for that.  You might want to submit a feature suggestion/feedback to them regarding an option to extend the tooltip removal delay.

Possible **workaround:**
Slowing one's double-click speed in the [mouse control panel *(screenshot)*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSQGq.png) can extend the amount of time a tooltip displays.  However, slowing the double-click speed becomes rather **inconvenient** when one finds oneself accidentally double-clicking on stuff that one meant to select and move.

As per the Microsoft [Tooltips and Infotips Guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742443.aspx#guidelines),*(2)* some applications use a multiple of the double-click speed delay - typically 10.  Assuming Android Studio respects this, if one's Windows double-click delay is set to about 400ms like in my mouse control panel screenshot, tooltips will remain for 4 seconds before disappearing.  Most people probably have it set to 480.

Testing with Notepad++, slowing my double-click speed to 880ms *(it goes in 80ms steps)* caused tooltips to remain for just under 9 seconds, so some applications respect that.  I'm not sure if Android Studio uses that approach.

**Another workaround** is decreasing the delay* before the tooltip displays, so you don't have to wait so long to read it again.
**-(as per your screenshot)*

**References:**

*[(1) Tooltips with infinite timeout?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/3931/tooltips-with-infinite-timeout) - UX.stackexchange.com*

*(2) (apparently I've exceeded my limit on links here, although it let me link Tooltips and Infotips Guidelines above)*

Answer (score 51):

If someone encounters this problem, it's related to the way the logcat refreshes.

Every time logcat refreshes, even if minimized, the tooltip will disappear, so it seems to be a bug with Android Studio (tried on 4.0).

Disconnecting from your device (so there's no logcat) will effectively keep the tooltip onscreen forever. This is not a fix but the current behavior.

It may become more apparent when logging with "No Filters", so I'd recommend logging "Show only selected application" which may minimize the effects if your application doesn't log too often.

Edit: As suggested in the comments, typing some random text in the Logcat search box will prevent the tooltip from disappearing, as long as nothing from the output matches the text. And you don't have to disconnect the device with this method.

Comment: Thanks! I added random characters to the "filter" in the logcat display and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Great finding. Still sucks though

Comment: Can confirm, also happening here (Android Studio 4.0.1 Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6626763, built on June 25, 2020)

Comment: Blind luck I guess, noticed tooltips stopped disappearing the instant I unplugged a device.

Comment: it only happens on Linux, always many issues with that system, Windows works fine

Comment: also if you type something for logcat filter and there is no new filtered logs it still disappears, so the only solution it's disconnect from device... annoying

Comment: THANKS! This was driving me insane! <3

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario, just change the default value of `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `General` -> `Other` -> `Tooltip delay` from `500ms` to any other value e.g `200ms`, then apply the changes, the hovered tooltip won't disappear so quickly.

So weirdly, I guess Android studio might wrongly interpret the `Tooltip delay` as `Tooltip disappear delay` for the default value.

Comment: thanks that worked, but i had to restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio 4.1.1 on MacOS the relevant setting appears to be

Preferences -> Editor -> Code Editing -> Editor Tooltips -> Tooltip delay: 5000 milliseconds

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and I managed to fix it by disabling [Fast-Scrolling plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7573-fast-scrolling) and then reenable it. (Thanks to Pankaj Kumar for the tip)