# Android Studio 4.0 red line tooltip suggestions disappearing too quickly to read

Tags: android-studio

I updated my Android Studio recently to 4.0 and now when I type code incorrectly, and I mouse over the red squiggly line to see what it expects or suggests, the tooltip appears and disappears very quickly. I can't read it. In fact, it's even harder now to get the thing to show up, it's very precise where the mouse pointer is. I've restarted everything including my computer. I've changed the tooltip settings from 700 to 2000 with no change. Anyone else have this issue and know how to fix it?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer via this link:

[Android Studio , tooltip disappearing so fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35341424/android-studio-tooltip-disappearing-so-fast)

Basically, put a bunch of random letters in your filter for Logcat and it will stop the messages, the tooltip will stay up. When Logcat is running it's interrupting the tooltips now for some reason. I think this must be a bug.